# Git push not seeing all my changes

Tags: git, github, gitignore

I created a private GitHub repo, say https://github.com/myuser/myprivrepo, and chose to have it generate a `.gitignore` and `README.md` for me. I then cloned this repo locally and added a bunch of files. I also modified both my `.gitignore` as well as the `README.md` that GitHub had generated for me.

I then did this:

```
git commit -a -m "Initial commit with basic project structure."
```

And then this:

```
git push
```

It asked me to authenticate, I did, and the "push" seemed to be successful. So I go back into my GitHub repo, and after refreshing the page, I still only see my two GitHub-generated files (`.gitignore` and `README.md`), however they have been updated with my changes and even show a correctly-updated timestamp and commit message ("*Initial commit with basic project structure.*") next to them.

So it's like the push honored the two GitHub-generated files being changed, but ignored all my other changes. Here is my `.gitignore`:

```
*.class
.mtj.tmp/
*.jar
*.war
*.ear
hs_err_pid*
.metadata
.gradle/
bin/
tmp/
*.tmp
*.bak
*.swp
*~.nib
local.properties
.settings/
.loadpath
.project
.externalToolBuilders/
*.launch
.cproject
.classpath
.buildpath
.target
.texlipse
```

And an example of a file that I added but that is not present on GitHub is `build.gradle`, which shouldn't be getting matched by anything in the ignore file. Thoughts?

**Note**: When I right-click my local repo root dir and go to `Git Gui` I see that all the files that are missing on GitHub are showing up locally as "Unstaged". Not sure if that means anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git commit -a` does not add files that were previously untracked. You can use `git add .` to add everything prior to the commit. The `-a` is not needed anymore then.

[Quoting the commit manual](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#_options) (emphasis mine):

> -a
> --all
>
> Tell the command to automatically stage files that have been modified and deleted, **but new files you have not told Git about are not affected**.

Answer (score 1):

It seems GitHub is fine. When you do a `git commit -a`, all the files that git was already tracking are committed, which in your case will be just the files generated by GitHub. New files will not be committed unless you `git add <file>` or `git commit <file>`. To check which files git is tracking, use `git ls-tree -r master --name-only`. It may also be useful to do a `git status` before commiting:

```bash
$ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        ### Files which will be committed with git commit -a appear here

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        ### Files which will NOT be committed with git commit -a appear here

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

To fix your current problem, you could do:

```bash
$ # uncommit last commit
$ git reset HEAD~1 --soft
$ # add missing file
$ git add build.gradle
$ # recommit
$ git commit -a -m "Initial commit with basic project structure."
$ # force the push, as git will complain about overwriting a commit
$ git push --force
```